# Select different column in a row depending on the value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return a friend list for my users and I'm trying to gather the value matching their user_id.

```
| ID | user1_id | user1_status | user2_id | user2_status |
| 1  | 1        |  0           |  2       | 0            |
| 2  | 4        |  1           |  5       | 1            |
| 3  | 4        |  1           |  6       | 0            |
| 4  | 1        |  0           |  4       | 1            |
```

Here is the problem I have, the value I'm look for can be in either "user1_id"/"user2_id" and then I need to return the "user_status" ONLY for the other user. n. I made this table really simple. In my version there is a lot more columns I want my server to avoid returning.

Let's say that the client user_id is 4, so I need the select all the row with user1_id/user2_id equal to 4 and return the other person user_status. In the table, the first case of the value equal to 4 is in user1_id, I need that row to return the user2_id and user2_status.

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT `id`
    CASE 
        WHEN `user1_id`='4' THEN `user2_id` AND `user2_status`
        WHEN `user2_id`='4' THEN `user1_id` AND `user1_status` 
    ELSE NULL
    END 
        from 'relationship' 
        where `user1_id`='4' OR `user2_id`='4'
```

How do I write this query statement?

Comment: Why do you have PHP tag?

Comment: Because I'm querying this in php, should I take it off?

Comment: This question ,I guess ,is only about SQL so you can remove PHP tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [CASE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) you will see that it's defined to return a single column and not a tuple. Additionally, in your query you are trying to get either (user2_id, user_status) or NULL. Here you get a mismatch in the number of columns which is not allowed either.

If you really really want to use CASE you could do:

```
SELECT `id`
    CASE 
        WHEN `user1_id`='4' THEN `user2_id`, 
        ELSE NULL
    END
    CASE 
        WHEN `user2_id`='4' THEN `user1_id`
        ELSE NULL
    END
    CASE
        WHEN `user1_id`='4' THEN `user1_status`
        ELSE NULL
    END
    CASE
        WHEN `user2_id`='4' THEN `user2_status`
        ELSE NULL
    END

    FROM 'relationship' 
        where `user1_id`='4' OR `user2_id`='4'
```

yes, clunky and confusing. Much Simpler if you use UNION.

```
SELECT id, user2_id AS uid, user2_status as ustatus FROM relationship WHERE user1_id = 4
UNION
SELECT id, user1_id AS uid, user1_status as ustatus FROM relationship WHERE user2_id = 4
```

Comment: you said "if" you refer to the CASE syntax. Is there a better way you would suggest? Because CASE syntax was the only way I thought mysql could do "if" statements. BTW Thank you so much, I'll give this a try. :)

Comment: Heh, you read my mind. Going to do some research in the "union" syntax.

Comment: Great. Just copy paste that second query into the mysql console for now :)

Comment: I had miss understood the CASE function, and thinking back on it now, I guess processing each argument in the row would have taken much longer. I was calling for two separate quering in php before this to get the same result here. I'm still sadden by the fact that it will search through the table twice, but with "union", it will save my sever from vertifying the query twice. Thank you, this work perfrectly!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Don't be too worried about the UNION, It's efficiency is about equal to the use of the OR logical operator in the where clause but you might need to tweak your indexes